# Web3 eth sendtransaction editable

Tags: ethereum, web3js, metamask

I want to make an eth payment on my website. I'm using a simple sendtransaction. How can I hide the edit button? Or how can I make the transaction not editable?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "edit" button is a non-configurable feature of the MetaMask browser extension.

So unless you can update the local copy of the MM code on each computer where you want the "edit" button to be hidden, there's no way to hide it.

Comment: On other websites (for example wonderland.money) if you want to deposit crypto there is no edit button in the top left corner. How did they make it not editable then?

Comment: @DaniKovács Most likely it's asking for a gas-free signature, not for a transaction. Can you provide repro steps or screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue and if you are dealing with any ERC-20 token it should have the "transfer" and "transferFrom" methods built into the contract. If you use "transfer" only 2 parameters are needed, toAddress and amount. transferFrom expects the previously mentioned fields as well as the an additional field, fromAddress. By using the transferFrom method you are giving the transaction all the information it needs to make a request so the user shouldnt need to edit the transaction.

https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/standards/tokens/erc-20/

Comment: I don't think this is what OP is doing. If so, they should specify it in the question. To me it seems they are testing receiving payment, and MetaMask is brokering the ETH transaction.

Answer (score 0):

It's just gas price edit button.

If you don't want to manually edit the gas price, you can set it in the Metamask: `Settings -> Advanced -> Advanced gas controls`, close it.